Try to get ListBox value from UserForm but I got this error: Run-time error 13: Type mismatch

Add a UserForm to the Power Point file.

Put a CommandButton and a ListBox on that UserForm.

Put the following codes under the UserForm.
 Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "msoShapePentagon"
     UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "msoShapeRectangle"
     UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "msoShapeSmileyFace"
 End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     MsgBox UserForm1.ListBox1.Value
     UserForm1.Hide
     Call Macro2
 End Sub


Put the following codes under the Module1 of Power Point file.
  Public Sub Macro1()
      UserForm1.Show
  End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 Public Sub Macro2()
     ActivePresentation.Slides.Add 1, ppLayoutBlank

     Dim myVariant As Variant
     myVariant = UserForm1.ListBox1.Value
     MsgBox myVariant

     'This line is okey
     'ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=480, Height:=100

     'This line gives an error
     ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape Type:=myVariant, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=480, Height:=100
  End Sub


Run Macro1 and then select msoShapeRectangle from ListBox which is part of the UserForm and press CommandButton.

This is the error message.
 Run-time error 13: Type mismatch


This is the error line
 ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape Type:=myVariant, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=480, Height:=100



So how can I solve that error?

"msoShapePentagon", a String, is not the same as msoShapePentagon, a member of an enum with a corresponding value of 51.
One option is a function to convert the String representation to the equivalent from the enum:
Private Function ShapeType(s As String) As MsoAutoShapeType
    Dim result As MsoAutoShapeType
    
    Select Case s
        Case "msoShapePentagon"
            result = msoShapePentagon
        Case "msoShapeRectangle"
            result = msoShapeRectangle
        Case "msoShapeSmileyFace"
            result = msoShapeSmileyFace
    End Select
    
    ShapeType = result
End Function

Note that you need to pass this function a String, not a Variant.

There are more than a hundred enum members as you linked. I dont want to code a hundred enum members.

That's the recommended approach. If you don't like it, then consider reading this thread.

Thank you Mr. BigBen. I have accepted my question solved until a better solution.
